# ld: Assertion failed: (src.atom != NULL), function addRelocFixup

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang, xcode4.6.3

I've added logic tests to my project and those appear to run ok, but now if I go back and run my project against the simulator, I get the following error. The project builds fine against a device.

Any ideas? Been tearing my hair out for a day or two trying to understand what is wrong..

```
0  0x105137098  __assert_rtn + 144
1  0x10513a431  mach_o::relocatable::Section<x86>::addRelocFixup(mach_o::relocatable::Parser<x86>&, macho_relocation_info<Pointer32<LittleEndian> > const*) + 1781
2  0x10514a636  mach_o::relocatable::Section<x86>::makeFixups(mach_o::relocatable::Parser<x86>&, mach_o::relocatable::Parser<x86>::CFI_CU_InfoArrays const&) + 90
3  0x105146aad  mach_o::relocatable::Parser<x86>::parse(mach_o::relocatable::ParserOptions const&) + 1433
4  0x10513e0c3  mach_o::relocatable::Parser<x86>::parse(unsigned char const*, unsigned long long, char const*, long, ld::File::Ordinal, mach_o::relocatable::ParserOptions const&) + 313
5  0x10513baa1  mach_o::relocatable::parse(unsigned char const*, unsigned long long, char const*, long, ld::File::Ordinal, mach_o::relocatable::ParserOptions const&) + 149
6  0x10515c33a  archive::File<x86>::makeObjectFileForMember(archive::File<x86>::Entry const*) const + 794
7  0x10515bc32  archive::File<x86>::forEachAtom(ld::File::AtomHandler&) const + 424
8  0x10516d76c  ld::tool::InputFiles::forEachInitialAtom(ld::File::AtomHandler&) + 420
9  0x105176884  ld::tool::Resolver::resolve() + 44
10  0x105137380  main + 370
A linker snapshot was created at:
/tmp/TagItApp-2013-06-22-153014.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (src.atom != NULL), function addRelocFixup, file /SourceCache/ld64/ld64-136/src/ld/parsers/macho_relocatable_file.cpp, line 5468.
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Try cleaning the project, the build folder, resetting the simulator, restarting Xcode and restarting the computer. Golden rule is to do all together :)

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, thanks... from some research online this appears to be a known apple bug. does anyone concur?

Comment: Well, I would say that iPhone Simulator is one big bug :D I always have problems with it, beginning with zombie objects, ending with weird malloc() behaviour.

Comment: Can we see the invocation please?

Comment: could be something to do with armv7 vs i386, if its running on device i wouldnt worry about simulator

Comment: I think it is architecture related. I thought I had fixed it, but now of course it's still an issue. Given that my app uses the camera, which is pretty useless on a simulator, perhaps I should just live with it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with the Bump library on my simulator. This thread provides a simulator friendly version of the lib: https://github.com/bumptech/bump-api-ios/issues/15